# I tried to launch h264 video files with gstreamer but got the gray video image

Tags: video, gstreamer, h.264

I don't know about gstreamer too much, but I'd like to convert h264 file from the surveillance camera because that video is really important!

I use this pipeline to launch the h264 video

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/filename.h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

The video can launch but the video looks like this
[image]

I don't know why. Is it because corrupted files or I did something wrong?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

That is because the resolution of the pipeline outcome is not matched with source resolution. You should filter the video as video/x-h264 and determine the width, height and frame rate properties accordingly. Then, you should be able to see the video. You can see the example below:

filesrc ... ! video/x-h264, width=1920, height=1080, frame-rate=30/1 ! ...